# Можно ли константную ссылку на строку проинициализировать временным значением, которое образуется при вызове функции?

Tags: c++, c++11

На собеседовании по С++ дали вот такой код:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

string func() {
    if (rand() % 2) {
        string str;
        str = "A";
        return str;
    } else {
        string str;
        str = "B";
        return str;
    }
}

int main() {
    const string& str = func();
    cout << "str: '" << str << "'" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

И спросили, можно ли константную ссылку на строку проинициализировать временным значением, которое образуется при вызове функции? Можно ли так делать?

Answer (score 0):

Так делать можно, код будет работать.

Время жизни временной `std::string`, которую возвращает функция, [продлевается до конца жизни ссылки](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary).

Но вообще, за такой код нужно бить по рукам.

Comment: Можно узнать, за что минус?